# Deploying PhoneGap Build App to Google Play Store: Multiple Keys?

Tags: android, cordova, keytool, phonegap-build

I built an app with PhoneGap Build. I signed it with a key and set the validity to 50000 days. PhoneGap seems to build it fine. So I download it and try to upload it to Google Play Store. And I get this error:

Your APK has been signed with multiple certificates. Please only sign it with one certificate and upload it again.
You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into the future.

?? I don't know what else to do or why it is signed with multiple certificates. I have a code signing cert from Go Daddy that is in pfx format. I used keystore to convert it to JKS format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just let Eclipse generate the cert for signing instead of using a 3rd party?
Might be some problem after converting it.

Comment: I am not using Eclipse. I will try to generate a new one from scratch. Is there no benefit to have a professionally verified code signing certificate?

Comment: No one cares where the cert is from nor if it is signed by a CA. It just has to be a cert that you can use for signing the Apps, and hopefully never lose it ;) It's not like with webpages where there is a icon for a trusted cert or a warning for a non-trusted one, much simpler here. A cert for signing, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that then. I had to get a code signing cert for a Windows application I'm developing. So figured it would be best to use the same verified certificate for both. Apparently just adds needless complication! Thanks.